# Category theory: definiton of a selector

Tags: category-theory

I am struggling with the concept of a selector in category theory (Harold Simmons, An introduction to category theory, Cambridge 2011, exercise 2.2.7). Let the category $C$ have a particular object $S$ with a special element $\star$ such that for each object $A$ and $a\in A$ there is a unique arrow $S\xrightarrow{\alpha } A$ with $\alpha(\star)=a$. It is claimed that each monic $m:A\rightarrow B$ in the category $C$ is injective. The solution in https://www.cambridge.org/cr/files/1813/6680/4928/SIMMONS-CATS-BIGSOL.pdf, p. 26, puzzles me. His argument goes as follows: Assume $a_1,a_2\in A$ and let $m(a_1)=m(a_2)$. It has to be shown that $a_1=a_2$. It is claimed that the composites $m\circ\alpha_1,m\circ\alpha_2$ are determined by their value at $\star$. Then $$(m\circ\alpha_1)(\star)=m(a_1)=m(a_2)=(m\circ\alpha_2)(\star).$$ Since $m$ is a monic, $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ which leads to $a_1=a_2$. What I do not understand is the choice of $a_1,a_2$. After all, such a selector maps to a particular element of $A$.

Is it by aforementioned definition of a selector, that for each element $a$ in $A$ a map $\alpha_{a,A}:S\rightarrow A$ such that $\alpha_{a,A}(\star)=a$ for a selector $S$? Furthermore, is this how a selector is defined?

Looking at the example of the category $Grp$ (exercise 2.2.7 part (b) in the solutions of Simmons), the selector is the group $(\mathbb{Z},+,0)$ with $\star=1$. Why is $\star$ so chosen? What role do the other elements of the selector (besides $\star$) play?

Comment: I have to say I'm not sure I really understand what puzzles you, but it seems that maybe it's a quantifier issue? Indeed, the definition that you wrote yourself is that for any choice of $a$ there exists a (unique) $\alpha_{a,A}$ such that $\alpha_{a,A}(\ast)=a$.

Comment: The question why each monic is injective is fine, so far, after some rethinking. The definition of $\alpha_{a,A}$ was my own notation and I was not sure whether the arrow in question was really meant in this way. I still struggle more with the selector for the example for the category Grp. Maybe someone can elucidate that example. There are other examples in the solutions to the exercise though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to focus on your question about the category of groups, since you say the rest is more or less ok.

It's actually exactly what it says on the box: for any group $G$ and any element $g\in G$, there is a unique group morphism $$f_{G,g}:\mathbb{Z}\to G$$
such that $f_{G,g}(1)=g$. It's fairly easy to prove, you just define $f_{g,G}$ by $f_{G,g}(n)=g^n\in G$, and you check that it's a group morphism, and that it's the only one with $f(1)=g$.